# Spring JPA resulting in error executing delete DDL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hello I'm new to Spring and I am trying to create a model which maps to a table in Apache Derby (using it for testing), the issue is I get a `Error executing DDL "drop table potatoes" via JDBC Statement`, I heard it is generally caused by using a SQL keyword however I don't think I'm using any:
Users.java:

```
@Entity
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String passwordHash;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String passwordHash) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using HQL - Hibernate Query Language and something like

```
entityManager.createQuery("drop table potatoes;").executeUpdate();
```

DROP is an invalid statement in HQL. If you want to use DROP you have to use not HQL, but SQL and native query.
Please try:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("drop table potatoes;").executeUpdate();
```